# Radino40 Breakout Board

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, bluetooth

I would like to control the [Radino40 breakout board](https://wiki.in-circuit.de/index.php5?title=radino40_DW1000_Breakout#Hardware) with arduino. But i don't know if is it possible. I know that the single [Radino40 DW1000](http://wiki.in-circuit.de/index.php5?title=radino40_DW1000) antenna could controlled by Arduino through SPI, but my board haven't this connection.

Comment: I think that the idea is you program the Radino40 directly with your own code. No reason you couldn't write code that accepts some data over serial from an Arduino.

Comment: I think so. The schematics of this board aren't clear and the documentation is bad. There are, available, more then 32 pin but i don't know how to connect.

Comment: It shows RX and TX pins, which implies that it has a UART, and it also has a micro USB connector. I don't see any indication of an SPI connection from the (scant) documentation.

Comment: it is a nRF52840 programmable over SWD. you can code for it with mbed or as Arduino with Arduino mbed package if you create a board definitions based on Arduino Nano 33 BLE board variant (it is nRF52840 too) and burn the Arduino bootloader